# Want to force zero in group by clause

Tags: sql-server

Hi here is my simple query

```
--Code formatting
select severity as measurement,
       count(tkts) as tkts
from Maintable
where (Bunch of conditions)
group by severity
```

I am getting correct result but it is not showing the severity where result is 0, I want to force all severity even if they had zero tickets.

Using SQL server 2012

Comment: May be the problem is with `where` clause?

Comment: Yeah, better to post it, even if you have to generalize unpublishables.

Comment: No I am still getting the same results. where clause is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Start with all severity values, and `left join` the main table:

```
select  sev.severity as measurement
,       count(mt.id) as tkts 
from    (
        values (1), (2), (3), (4), ..., (N)
        ) sev(severity)
left join
        (
        select  *
        from    Maintable 
        where   <bunch of conditions>
        ) mt
on      mt.severity = sev.severity
group by 
        sev.severity
```

Per your comment, to add a tier:

```
select  sev.severity as severity_name
,       tier.tier as tier_name
,       count(mt.id) as tkts 
from    (
        values (1), (2), (3), (4), ..., (N)
        ) sev(severity)
cross join
        (
        values ('A'), ('A2'), ('B'), ..., ('last')
        ) tier(tier)
left join
        (
        select  *
        from    Maintable 
        where   <bunch of conditions>
        ) mt
on      mt.severity = sev.severity
        and mt.iter = tier.tier
group by 
        sev.severity
,       tier.tier
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you so much! I got it.

Comment: If I want to add one more layer of tier type in between the severity and tkts, what do I do ? so like this.   SEVERITY, TIER, TKTS and again force all the zeros. tier types can be 2 2L 3 3i etc

Comment: You can add another tier with a `cross join`, added to answer